# Read&Write Numbers to .txt using ETL and SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, xls

I'm writing a .txt from an .xls file.
I'm using JasperETL to read the excel and insert data into MSSQL and then write the .txt file.

In the excel file, i have a Number (amount of money) that looks like this `20.000,00` but sometimes, due to regional settings, that number is imported in SQL as `20,000.00` (separators are inverted - , becomes . and . becomes ,).

My final format needs to look like this `20000.00` and for that i'm using the REPLACE function in MSSQL.

Is there any way, using a T-SQL query, to overcome this issue?

I've been thinking to use the old way and make CASES for each possible format, something like this.

```
CASE WHEN sum like 'x.xxx,xx' THEN...
WHEN sum like 'x,xxx.xx' THEN...
```

But i'm also looking for alternatives.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not familiar with JasperETL, but I would recommend enforcing a uniform standard as early in your process as possible.  If the Excel source files are the root cause of this variation, can you detect and import uniformly in JasperETL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually fixed this issue with an SQL Query

If anyone is in my situation, here is the answer

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',@test) > CHARINDEX(',',@test) THEN REPLACE(@test,',','')
WHEN CHARINDEX('.',@test) < CHARINDEX(',',@test) THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(@test,'.',''),',','.')

Replace @test with your column
```